# KeyError while using sklearn.feature_extraction.text

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', stop_words='english')

age_matrix = tfidf.fit_transform(df['age'])
```

When running the above code following error may occur.

Why does this happen?

Please, help me.
Thanks in advance.

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in
> get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2895                 return
> self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)    2896             except KeyError
> as err:
> -> 2897                 raise KeyError(key) from err    2898     2899         if tolerance is not None:
>
> KeyError: 'age'

My dataset as follows.

```
        Gender                      product  0
age                                       
18       F                    Bags-Mens  5
18       F                   Bags-Women  4
18       F               Books-Academic  4
18       F               Books-Children  5
18       F                 Books-Comics  7
..     ...                          ... ..
44       M                 Books-Comics  2
44       M                Clothing-Mens  1
44       M               Clothing-Women  1
44       M               Footwear-Women  1
44       M  Home and kitchen-Furnishing  2

[1202 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that *'age'* is the data frame index (and not a column) so you can't access it by *df['age']*.

You can just pass *df.index* instead to the fit_transform method.